# Use of Language Helpers in CoffeeScript in assigning prototypal properties

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, javascript-objects

I have a CoffeeScript code, which is a driver code for neo4j. In that it has a class `PropertyContainer` which has two function `get` and `set` which are listed as language helpers. and below that are `self` and `data` , which are basically prototypical properties of this object. these can be accessed like `a.self` and `a.data`.

What i don't understand is why their is a `get` and `set` before them, in the following code. the `get` and `set` clearly identifies here is the property is being read or written to but how is it working. In CoffeeScript you define prototypical properties as, s `prop_name: -> somecode` but if you put `get prop_name: -> somecode` shouldn't this change the property name to something that get returned after `get prop_name`. I am very new to CoffeeScript, so maybe i am missing something. Please Help.

```
class PropertyContainer

    #
    # Construct a new wrapper around a Neo4j property container with the given
    # data directly from the server at the given Neo4j {GraphDatabase}.
    #
    # @private
    # @param db {GraphDatbase}
    # @param data {Object}
    #
    constructor: (db, data) ->
        @db = db
        @_request = db._request     # convenience alias

        @_data = data or {}
        @_data.self = data?.self or null

    ### Language helpers: ###

    get = (props) =>
        @::__defineGetter__ name, getter for name, getter of props
    set = (props) =>
        @::__defineSetter__ name, setter for name, setter of props

    ### Properties: ###

    #
    # @property {String} The URL of this property container.
    #
    # @todo This might be an implementation detail; should we remove it?
    #   If not, should it at least be renamed to just URL?
    #
    get self: -> @_data.self or null

    #
    # @property {Object} This property container's properties. This is a map
    #   of key-value pairs.
    #
    get data: -> @_data.data or null
    set data: (value) -> @_data.data = value
```

This is actually a Driver for Neo4j based on REST API. I don't think it has anything to do with the GET method of HTTP. i have checked for `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__`, these are nowhere else to be seen in the whole library, except for when used in a similar way for other Classes. May be these are some CoffeeScript internal Prototype Prototypes. Would love if anyone could shed some light on this. Thanks again.

Comment: i found a place which explains the purpose of `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter) i think i understood the part that `get` and `set` are just function calls to bind the properties `self` and `data` to the functions that passed as a key value argument to the `get` and `set` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CoffeeScript class is a function definition with a bunch of class-ish stuff layered on top. This means that you can put pretty any code you want inside a class. So if we look at this:

```
class C
    f = -> #...
    f(6)
```

then we have a private function, `f`, and a simple function call, `f(6)`.

Now if we add a [`=>`](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) in the mix:

```
class C
    f = => #...
```

then `f` becomes bound to the class so that `@` inside `f` will be `C` itself.

Now we can apply that to the class in question:

```
class PropertyContainer
    #...

    get = (props) =>
        @::__defineGetter__ name, getter for name, getter of props
    set = (props) =>
        @::__defineSetter__ name, setter for name, setter of props

    get self: -> @_data.self or null
```

So we have two functions, `get` and `set`, that are abound to `PropertyContainer` so that `@` inside `get` and `set` is `PropertyContainer`. Then we have a call to the `get` function and adding some parentheses and braces to highlight the structure:

```
get({ self: (-> @_data.self or null ) })
```

we should start to see what's going on. The `get self ...` is just a call to the `get` function with an object parameter, that object has a single key (`self`) whose value is a function.

That makes the whole `get self ...` call look like this:

```
PropertyContainer::__defineGetter__('self', -> @_data.self or null)
```

Then if we look at what [`__defineGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter) does:

```
// Non-standard and deprecated way
var o = {};
o.__defineGetter__("gimmeFive", function() { return 5; });
console.log(o.gimmeFive); // 5
```

we see that we're just setting up `o.self` as an accessor alias for `o._data.self` so that this:

```
o = new PropertyContainer(...)
o.self
```

is really the same as:

```
o = new PropertyContainer(...)
o._data.self
```

or more generally, the `get` function allows you to send a simple property access to a function. You should also note the "standard compliant" examples from the MDN page:

```
// Using the get operator
var o = { get gimmeFive() {return 5}};
console.log(o.gimmeFive); // 5
```

Now we see that `get` inside `PropertyContainer` is emulating JavaScript's [`get` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get) using the non-standard `__defineGetter__` function.

The `set` function inside `PropertyContainer` similarly emulates JavaScript's [`set` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/set).

Comment: Thanks @mu-is-too-short, Great Explanation. description of `=>` is partcularly very helpful.